# call a function (defined in a subroutine) in another function

Tags: fortran

I am writing code in fortran for 2D integral for function func(x,y) with limits on y from y1(x) to y2(x) and limits on x from x1=3 to x2=5.
Basic assumptions are as follows:
Integral[func(x,y),{y=y1 to y2}, {x=x1 to x2}] = Integral[funcx(x),{x = x1 to x2}]. where funcx = Integral[func,{y = y1(x) to y2(x)}]

Please find my question in the middle of code. I write the code as follows,

```
implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)

external func
external y1
external y2

x1 = 3.d0
x2 = 5.d0

call twodint(func,y1,y2,x1,x2,result)
print*, result

stop
end
```

!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
subroutine twodint(origfunc,y1,y2,x1,x2,result) 
implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
external funcx
call simpsonintegral(funcx,x1,x2,ss) ! my integral routine funcx = function, x1 and x2 = limits, ss = output 
result = ss
return
end
```

!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
function funcx(x)
implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
external funcy
external y1
external y2
common/xvalues/xx
xx = x
call simpsonintegral(funcy,y1(x),y2(x),ss)
funcx = ss
return
end
```

!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
function funcy(y)
implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
common/xvalues/x
```

!   my question : if i write here funcy = func(x,y), my code works fine. but i want to write here something like funcy = origfunc(x,y), so that it can receive function from subroutine named as twodint. but this does not work. please help...
    return
    end

!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
function func(x,y)
implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
func = (x**2)*y*dsin(x*y) ! some function of x and y
return
end

function y1(x)
implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
y1 = x ! some limit
return
end

function y2(x)
implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
y2 = x*x ! some limit
return
end
```

Comment: How it does not work? Through which subroutine should it receive the original? Please do not write in ALL CAPS!

Comment: @VladimirF I passed the function in subroutine twodint by name origfunc and want it to be received at the point where I asked the question. Please let me know if any more clarification is required.

Comment: Who knows, your program is full of the ugly `implicit` and `external` statements and it is difficult to comprehend. At least for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `external` is mainly included in modern Fortran for legacy reasons.   Its not the best way to pass functions to subroutines.  Also, implicit type declaration is dangerous ... much better to use `implicit none` and explicitly type all of your variables ... you'll catch a lot of mistakes that way.  So ... here is a sketch of how to pass various functions to a subroutine such as an integrator.

```
module MyStuff

implicit none

abstract interface
  function funcX (x)
      real, intent (in) :: x
      real :: funcX
  end function funcX
end interface



contains

subroutine twodint(origfunc,y1,y2,x1,x2,result)

real :: y1, y2, x1, x2, result, ss
procedure (funcX) :: origfunc

call simpsonintegral (origfunc,x1,x2,ss) ! my integral routine funcx = function, x1 and x2 = limits, ss = output
result = ss
return
end subroutine twodint


real function funcA (x)
real, intent (in) :: x
funcA = x ** 2
end function funcA

real function funcB (x)
real, intent (in) :: x
funcB = x ** 2
end function funcB

end module MyStuff


program test1

use MyStuff

implicit none



real :: x1, x2, y1, y2, result


x1 = 3.d0
x2 = 5.d0

call twodint(funcA,y1,y2,x1,x2,result)
print*, result

call twodint(funcB,y1,y2,x1,x2,result)
print*, result

stop
end program test1
```

Comment: I have the same feeling, get rid of `implicit` and `external`. Just note you have some spurious stars at the end of the code end the reals should probably be of a higher kind if you initialize it by double precision constants.

Comment: Vladmir F: good points.  I edited to remove the spurious characters.